# iostream, cin, потоки и непонятки

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Было так:

```
while (1) {
    cin >> tmp;
    if (tmp = -1)
        break;
    vec.push_back(tmp);
};
```

есть цикл ввода значений в массив, для того что бы его остановить нужно было ввести `-1`... Что не круто и не правильно. Решил переписать, и сделать остановку ввода значений по сочетанию клавиш ctrl+z (^Z).

Стало так:

```
while (cin.good()) {
    cin >> tmp;
    if (!cin.good())
        break;
    vec.push_back(tmp);
};
```

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда программа просто пропускает строки `cin >> tmp` в других блока кода ниже. Как я понял из за того, что в потоке еще что-то есть, оно это записывает в `tmp` и шурует дальше, не дав пользователю ввести значения.
Пробовал покуралесить с `cin.ignore()` и `cin.clear()` перед и после циклов. Смог достигнуть результата с `cin.clear()` после цикла 1 ввода, но там приходится вводить значения в массив с нажатием клавиши Enter что не удобно. Да и косяки мелкие все же остались.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать отмену ввода значений в массив нормальным образом. Опыта пока у самого не хватает :(

Вот исходный код пары блоков:
(один создает массив другой вводит значения в конец массива, блоки практически по коду одинаковые и можно было бы вынести в отдельную функцию но я убрал немного лишнего с блоков что бы вам не мешало, проверки всякие) Сперва вызывается

```
case 50: {
  system("cls");
  ShowResult(vec);         // Показать элементы массива
  cout << "Введите значения: ";

  while (cin.good()) {
    cin >> tmp;         // Этот син работает хорошо, все корректно записывается
    if (!cin.good())
      break;
    vec.push_back(tmp); // добавить значение в конец массива
  };

  cin.clear();
  ShowResult(vec);
  system("pause");
  Start();
}   break;




case 51: {
system("cls");
ShowResult(vec);         // Показать элементы массива
cout << "Введите значения: ";

while (cin.good()) {
    cin >> tmp;         // Этот син он пропускает, и записывает в тмп последнее значение из 1 блока
    if (!cin.good())
        break;
    vec.push_back(tmp); // добавить значение в конец массива
};

cin.clear();
ShowResult(vec);
system("pause");
Start();
}   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Может быть попробовать чистить буфер потока ввода перед каждым циклом ввода массива

```
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

Он будет читать из входного потока до тех пор, пока не встретит EOF. Насколько разбираюсь, `std::cin.clear()`, эта функция просто сбрасывает состояние потоке ввода, то есть переводит его в рабочее состояние, она не удаляет символы из потока ввода. Поправьте, если не так.

`INT_MAX` можно заменить в С++11 следующим образом

```
#include <limits>
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный цикл чтения это

```
while (cin >> tmp)
    vec.push_back(tmp);
```

У `istream` (в т.ч. `cin`) есть оператор преобразования к `bool`, а операция `>>` возвращает `istream&`.

Comment: Да, так тоже работает. Но боюсь моя проблема не решена. В дебаге, если идти построчно: когда 1 блок когда, заполнение массива пройден. Во втором блоке, прогамма просто смотрит условие цикла и тут же завершается.